# Powershell script to get status of web site whether it is running or stopped in IIS manager

Tags: powershell

I have created a script to get the website status is running or stopped from IIS manager.

But i coudln't get exact output.

Question: just i need to display website status is running or stopped in IIS using scripts.

```
$serverList = 'SSCCL35'
foreach ($server in $serverList) {
$iis = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'sample'" -ComputerName $server
if ($iis.State -eq 'Running') { Write-Host "IIS is running on $server" }
Else { Write-Host "IIS is NOT running on $server" -ForegroundColor Red }
}
```

Note: "Sample" Service is running in my IIS. But i get output as "Not running".

Comment: You are querying _IIS service_ status instead or _website_ status. Check [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-ScriptFunction-afeab585).

Answer (score 2):

The current example shows you looking for a *service* named "sample", not a site named "sample", which is why it's always stating that it's not running.

From the local IIS host, you could find it using `AppCmd`:

```
Invoke-Expression "$env:SystemRoot\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list site 'sample'"
```

OR you could use the WebAdministration module to go pure Powershell (if it's available on the IIS host):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-WebsiteState -Name "sample"
```

If you want to run the command on remote servers, you'll need to use `Invoke-Command` and add one of those lines to the `ScriptBlock`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {enter one of the above lines of code here}
```